# Finding all Cells with Constants Crashes Excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop

I'm trying to find the count of all cell with constants using Excel Interop assembly.

On small files this works fine. However on larger files excel crashes.

I tried it on a file with 206963 rows and 9 columns and excel crashed.

1. Anyone know of a workaround?
2. Is there a list of the limitations of
   the [SpecialCells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.specialcells.aspx) function and when it should not be used?

The following is my code:

```
public static int getConstantCount(Range myRange) //myRange = myWorksheet.UsedRange
{
    try
    {    
        return myRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).Count;
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I noticed this also happens in excel itself without using any Interop assemblies. Look at https://superuser.com/questions/632856/excel-go-to-special-crashes-on-large-file

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Just the first idea...

Try to use `.CountLarge property` instead of `.Count property` you use currently.

At the moment you probably don't exceed the limit for `.Count` but I hope it could help.

[MSDN for `.Count` property (VBA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193349%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't think that will matter. It doesn't reach that number.